# React Context Folder hiarchy / architecture?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently looking at implementing Context into one of our apps over Redux, but, I can't seem to find any information on what would be the best structure for large scale apps?

Redux has a defined way to create reducers, actions, etc. With Context, all I've found are the generic "create a provider, put state and methods all on the same file, and then use a consumer".

**TL;DR Is there a way to build a hiarchy that is beneficial for long term, and large scale applications with React Context?**

**Edit:** I guess this is incorrect to think of them having a similar structured relationship. Unfortunately, I'm not able to use Redux because of AEM's limitations. Context does work however, so I wanted to hopefully be able to build some structure with that.

Comment: "over Redux" - you mean replacing Redux with Context? If that's the case, I wouldn't recommend this. _"Apply it sparingly because it makes component reuse more difficult."_ - from [Context docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). I'd look into [component composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) instead.

Comment: I need to update reason behind it on my post. I can't use Redux with AEM, so have to find an alternative that may work... Such as Context, which I don't want to be messy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I don't think there is necessarily a right or wrong answer to this question, but I will just give you my two cents.

I am currently refactoring a web application which serves several millions of sessions per month and am testing a redux and context version on internal stage servers.

Important notices:

- I am using a mono-store approach
- It's not an app which constantly has global store updates

To the folder structure. I like to keep my store in the root of the project. For a react app based on react-create-react-app that would be the `/src` and it basically consists of the following files:

- index.js // everything gets "bundled" here
- initialState.js // provides the store with intial state e.g. from server, cache etc.
- methods/*.js // contains split methods based on the part of the app that they are used in (if it can be split into separate parts)

Ergo my index.js is as simple as:

```
import React from 'react';
import storeMethods from './methods';
import initialState from './initialState';

// to start of experimenting with context
// i would keep all read and write key value
// pairs right here and split as the codebase
// grows and you realize you need more space
export const store = {
  ...initialState,
  ...storeMethods
}

export const StoreContext = React.createContext(store)
```

**storeMethods** is a bundled export from all `methods` in the `methods/` folder. Basically it's just another object of containing keys which values are functions like so:

```
export const methods = {
   showNavBar: function() {
      this.setState({ navBarOpen: true })
   }
}
```

**initialState** is as much as the representation of key value pairs that are required to render the base content of the app and or never change. Basically some global settings. Initialstate coming from the server, is being added to the store in the constructor of my App, right before I bind the lexical scope.

The store get's thrown into the state of the relevant outermost React Component and is used as the app state, where I bind the store's scope to the React Components lexical scope.

Then I have a higher order component `withContextConsumer` which is used to wrap any React component which needs access to the state. The HOC distributes the subscribed keys down as props to the wrapped component and can be consumed as read only or write.

No matter how you end up using Context, don't forget, that any Consumer will have it's render method automatically called if the Context Store is being updated. To avoid that on a simple `oldProps !== newProps` level, you can use PureComponents. For more complex diffs you can use the lifecyclemethod `shouldComponentUpdate`

**edit**

Basic App Structure

App.js:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { StoreContext, store } from './store'
import { bindScopeToFunction } from './helpers'

class App extends PureComponent {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      const { initialState = {} } = props
      const boundStore = bindScopeToFunction(store, this)
      this.state = {...boundStore, ...initialState}
   }
   render () {
      return(
         <StoreContext.Provider value={this.state}>
            // in here you render all your app
            // routing, childcomponents etc
            // in any component where you need access
            // to the global store
            // wrap it in <StoreContext.Consumer> it has
            // the whole store as render prop
         </StoreContext.Provider>
      )
   }
}
```

Working basic example can be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/pm85w4y6xm

Comment: This makes me feel a lot better.. Could you possibly share some code examples for what you're doing in your storeMethods and initialState?

Comment: Hope this helps in a way. We are in an interesting state, where no big player wrote any structured blogg article about how to and how not to use context. So I am currently experimenting with this approach. But also developing a redux version along the way to swap it out if it fails hard.

Comment: Tried to get your answer to work, don't understand the structure overall for providers etc with this.. :(

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: No example of binding methods on there?

Comment: no, can't share exact working code, but the idea behind bindScopeToFunction is that all the keys are being enhanced with .bind(this) // the this that you pass as an argument